# How to match a word in regex

Tags: java, regex

(//.[com]{3,3})

After trying the code it see both :. com & moc
Please is there way to make it see only com

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't need brackets, this means that you want a single character from the list `[com]`.

Try this: `//.com`.